# What happens when I copy a file from one network location to another

Tags: nfs, cp

Suppose I have three networked computers: A, B and C.

A mounts a directory from B and from C.

```
A/mnt/im-on-B/
A/mnt/im-on-C/
```

A then copies a file:

```
cp /mnt/im-on-B/file ../im-on-C/
```

What happens to the data - does it pass from B to C via A?

Is this significantly more inefficient than `cp`ing the file from B to C directly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both questions. B transmits the data to A, which retransmits it to C.  This means there's twice as much activity on the network as a direct copy from B to C would generate.  How significant that is depends on the topology of your network and what other traffic there is.

The standard workaround is to SSH into either B or C, and then start the copy from there (using NFS mounts or scp or rsync or whatever).  That way, the data goes directly from B to C and doesn't need to pass through or be duplicated by A.

Comment: is there a way (system utility) to directly copy it from B to C from A but not passing the data through A?

Comment: @foampile You could simply SSH into B or C computer and do you file operations bypassing A. There is a way to put SSH commands into a script and run it from A. [How to ssh from within a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895185/how-to-ssh-from-within-a-bash-script).